thoughts on using polymer-modified thinset mortar to parge a foundation?
Polymer-modified thinset is water-resistant, adhesive, and strong. Why is it not recommended to parge an exterior of a foundation? I just used VersaBond Fast-Setting Professional Thinset Mortar to parge my foundation, and it looked great. The coat has a thickness of at least an inch, and it's very strong although the manufacturer recommend not to make it thicker than 1/4 of an inch.
People say Type-S mortar is recommended. Isn't parging mortar meant to be sacrificial and weaker than the foundation? Isn't Type-S mortar too strong?
